# Self-referencing a table for previous record matching user ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, window-functions

I'm trying to find the easiest way to calculate cycle times from SQL data. In the data source I have unique station ID's, user ID's, and a date/time stamp, along with other data they are performing.

What I want to do is join the table to itself so that for each date/time stamp I get: 
 - the date/time stamp of the most recent previous instance of that user ID within 3 minutes or null
 - the difference between those two stamps (the cycle time = amount of time between records)

This should be simple but I can't wrap my brain around it. Any help?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and what YOU mean by "cycle time" would all help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff cycle time clarified. I'd supply sample data but it's NDA. I think GMB got it, though

Comment: Btw, if GMB's quers returns the correct result, my query does the same and is probably more efficient :-)

Comment: @dnoeth I did try yours, but I let it run for about 5 minutes and it didn't give a response, not even partial rows.

Comment: Ok, strange. How big is that table? How fast is the OUTER APPLY version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server does not support date range specifications in window functions. I would recommend a lateral join here:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    t1.timestamp last_timestamp, 
    datediff(second, t1.timestamp, t.timestamp) diff_seconds
from mytable t
outer apply (
    select top(1) t1.*
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.user_id = t.user_id 
        and t1.timestamp >= dateadd(minute, -3, t.timestamp)
        and t1.timestamp < t.timestamp
    order by t1.timestamp desc
) t1
```

The subquery brings the most recent row within 3 minutes for the same `user_id` (or an empty resultset, if there is no row within that timeframe). You can then use that information in the outer query to display the corresponding `timestamp`, and compute the difference with the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply calculate the difference of the current and the LAG timestamp, if it's more than three minutes return NULL instead:

```
with cte as
 (
   select 
      t.*
     ,datediff(second, timestamp, lag(timestamp) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as diff_seconds
   from mytable as t
 )
select cte.*
  ,case when diff_seconds <= 180 then diff_seconds end
from cte
```